# Type does not conform to an undefined protocol

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

In Xcode 6 Beta 2 I have written the following class:

```
class Item : Printable, Hashable {
    var description:String {
     return "..."
    }
    var hashValue:Int {
        return 1
    }
}
```

I am receiving an error stating that the Type 'Item' does not conform to the protocol 'Equatable' even though I have not tried to implement a protocol called 'Equatable.' Has anyone seen behavior like this? Any solution or workaround? thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the `Hashable` docs:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/CollectionTypes.html) (see the very bottom of that page)

> Types that conform to the Hashable protocol must provide a gettable Int property called hashValue, **and must also provide an implementation of the “is equal” operator (==).**

And according to [the `Equatable` docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Equatable.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014608-CH17-SW1) you do that by defining an operator overload function for `==` where the type you want is on each side of the operator.

```
func == (lhs: MyStruct, rhs: MyStruct) -> Bool {
    return lhs.name == rhs.name
}
```

Which means your code something like this:

```
class Item : Printable, Hashable {
    var description:String {
        return "..."
    }
    var hashValue:Int {
        return 1
    }
}

func == (lhs: Item, rhs: Item) -> Bool {
    return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
}

// Testing...
Item() == Item() //-> true
```

Assuming `hashValue` is what you think would make them equivalent, of course.

Comment: Why can't you just conform to *Equatable* protocol but then implement using `lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue`?

Answer (score 2):

The `Hashable` protocol implements the `Equatable` protocol, hence the reason why the compiler complains